# Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase takes a long time in Azure Automation

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-automation

We are using Azure SQL in our development environment and to reduce cost, we have created an Azure Automation runbook to scale down/up the Azure SQL instances. During working hours the databases are running with P2 and outside working hours they fall back to standard. This works fine, but there is a catch...

After a few days the runbook stopped working, because "*the quota for the monthly total job run time has been reached*". After some investigation it seems that the runbook takes about 30-45 minutes to complete.

I suspect that the runbook waits until the database is actually in the desired state. When I run the `Set-AzureRmSqlDatabase` from the command-line, then it returns immediately. How can I reproduce this with Azure Automation?

I am using the **Scale an Azure SQL DB to a specified edition and tier** from the Automation Gallery. Maybe I could create a custom script, but I would rather use standard scripts...

Comment: I'll see if I can find the person who made the Automation Gallery runbook you're asking about (it may take some time); I suspect the reason why it does this is to catch failures and be able to definitively say after running the runbook that a DB is in a specific state (upgraded to desired tier).

Comment: Are runbook sources available on GitHub somewhere? I couldn't find them.